# Radio button with radar plot shiny

Tags: shiny, radar-chart

I'm trying to make a shiny dashboard with attributes of superheros graphed in a radar plot. I'd also like to be able to use radio buttons to select which of the superheros I'd like to see in the graph. However, when I run this code, I get an error that says: Error in polygon: invalid value specified for graphical parameter "lwd". There is no lwd command that I'm aware of for radar charts so I'm not sure how to correct this. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to handle this error?

```
library(fmsb)

data<-data.frame(Strength = c(7, 0, 6, 7, 4, 3), 
                 Speed = c(7, 0 , 5, 7, 3, 2),
                 Intelligence = c(7, 0, 6, 2, 4, 3),
                 Fighting_Skills = c(7, 0, 4, 4, 4, 6),
                 Energy = c(7, 0, 6, 6, 1, 1),
                 Durability = c(7, 0, 6, 6, 3, 3),
                 row.names = c("max", "min", "Iron Man", "Thor", "Spiderman", "Captain America"))
head(data)

colors_fill<-c(scales::alpha("gray", 0.1))
               #scales::alpha("gold", 0.1),
               #scales::alpha("tomato", 0.2),
               #scales::alpha("skyblue", 0.2))


colors_line<-c(scales::alpha("darkgray", 0.9))
               #scales::alpha("gold", 0.9),
               #scales::alpha("tomato", 0.9),
               #scales::alpha("royalblue", 0.9))


#radarchart(data,
           #seg =7,
           #title = "Radar Chart",
           #pcol = colors_line,
           #pfcol = colors_fill, 
           #plwd = 1)

#legend(x = 0.6,
       #y=1.35,
       #legend = rownames(data[-c(1,2),]),
      # bty = "n", pch = 20, col = colors_line, cex = 1.2, pt.cex = 3)


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Radar chart"),

    # Sidebar with a radio buttons for person
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("variablechoice", "People Choice", 
                         choices = c("Iron Man", "Thor", "Spiderman", "Captain America"),
                         selected = "Thor")
        ),
        

        # Show a plot
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("radar")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a radar plot
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$radar <- renderPlot({
      if( input$variablechoice=="Iron Man"){new<-data[c(3),] }
      if( input$variablechoice=="Thor"){new<-data[c(4),] }
      if( input$variablechoice=="Spiderman"){new<-data[c(5),] }
      if( input$variablechoice=="Captain America"){new<-data[c(6),] }
      
      radarchart(new,
                 seg = 7,
                 #title = "Radar Chart",
                 pcol = colors_line,
                 pfcol = colors_fill, 
                 plwd = 0.5)
      
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have missed to include the first two rows of your data which contain the min and max values for the categories in your `new` dataframe. That's why `radarchart` throws an error:

```
library(fmsb)
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(
  Strength = c(7, 0, 6, 7, 4, 3),
  Speed = c(7, 0, 5, 7, 3, 2),
  Intelligence = c(7, 0, 6, 2, 4, 3),
  Fighting_Skills = c(7, 0, 4, 4, 4, 6),
  Energy = c(7, 0, 6, 6, 1, 1),
  Durability = c(7, 0, 6, 6, 3, 3),
  row.names = c("max", "min", "Iron Man", "Thor", "Spiderman", "Captain America")
)

colors_fill <- c(scales::alpha("gray", 0.1))
colors_line <- c(scales::alpha("darkgray", 0.9))

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Radar chart"),

  # Sidebar with a radio buttons for person
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("variablechoice", "People Choice",
        choices = c("Iron Man", "Thor", "Spiderman", "Captain America"),
        selected = "Thor"
      )
    ),
    # Show a plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("radar")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a radar plot
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$radar <- renderPlot({
    if (input$variablechoice == "Iron Man") {
      new <- data[c(1:2, 3), ]
    }
    if (input$variablechoice == "Thor") {
      new <- data[c(1:2, 4), ]
    }
    if (input$variablechoice == "Spiderman") {
      new <- data[c(1:2, 5), ]
    }
    if (input$variablechoice == "Captain America") {
      new <- data[c(1:2, 6), ]
    }

    radarchart(new,
      seg = 7,
      # title = "Radar Chart",
      pcol = colors_line,
      pfcol = colors_fill,
      plwd = 0.5
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense, and that did it, thank you so much for your help!